# Comparing performance of two SQL queries: one with a Self-Join v. two small queries without joins

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I am working on a project that must query a table, and I am torn between two simple SQL implementations. The real table contains many unrelated columns, but for this question's purpose, I'll create a simplified table named `[dbo].[Sample]`. `TableId` is a self-incrementing primary key; `UserId` is UNIQUE and a foreign key; `GroupId` is NOT UNIQUE, but is also a foreign key.

I am showing an example of data in the table here:

```
TableId       UserId          GroupId   
----------------------------------------
   1           384               2
   2           416               1
   3           498               2
   4           515               2
```

I have to obtain the UserIds of all entries in the sample table that have the same `GroupId` as X, a user passed in as a parameter: for example, if X had UserId 384, my query would return {498, 515} because they also have the same GroupId of 2.

The "complication" stems from not knowing X's GroupId before the query: i.e., I know X's UserId is 384, but I do NOT know their GroupId. I initially wrote a query utilizing an inner self-join:

```
  SELECT S2.UserId
  FROM Sample AS S1
  JOIN Sample AS S2 ON S1.UserId = X.UserId
                    AND S2.GroupId = S1.GroupId
                    AND S2.UserId != X.UserId -- do not return X's UserId
```

This query worked, but I hesitated about utilizing the JOIN — even though the `UserId` column is unique — because there are myriad records in the `Sample` table.

Thus, I wrote another solution that utilized two queries, obviating the need for a JOIN:

```
  DECLARE @GroupId AS INT

  SELECT @GroupId = SELECT GroupId 
                    FROM Sample 
                    WHERE UserId = X.UserId

  SELECT UserId 
  FROM Sample 
  WHERE GroupId = @GroupId AND UserId != X.UserId
```

Is the latter query more efficient?

I tested both queries on the dev database and did not notice any performance difference.

Comment: You need to test with large amounts of data to see a difference. But, no, breaking this in to two won't save any runtime cost. Stick with the single query, but move the `X.id` references to the `WHERE` clause for readability. *(Side note; adding two indexes will make these as fast as they get; `(user_id, group_id)` to make finding X's group faster, and `(group_id, user_id)` to make finding the group members faster.)*

Comment: The second option can be compressed into as single query as well: `SELECT UserId 
FROM Sample WHERE UserId != X.UserId and GroupId = (SELECT GroupId FROM Sample WHERE UserId = X.UserId)`.

Comment: Post the execution plans to compare. Useful comparisons should be done with a decent amount of data (tens of thousands of rows at least). With few rows, you won't really notice any difference.

Comment: Performance troubleshooting is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.